# View controller is not instantiating to Home VC when pressing login button

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

When I login to my app the Home view contoller does not appear and throws an error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional. This really irritates me - however there is no any syntax error I found.

Login view controller:

```
 @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {
 let vc : UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
 self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Home view controller:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var mainHomeButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mainHomeButton.target = SWRevealViewController()
    mainHomeButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
}
```

Architecture:

[image]

Comment: Is your `UIViewController` identifier correct?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: yes, Your identifier should be same in the storyboard and in the referencing class for that UIViewController.

Comment: what is `Stack trace` @Jonathan

Comment: yes it is correct @Rikh

Comment: your SWRevealViewController() might be nil

Comment: yes! , sir @Dory

Comment: how it can be nil any idea? @Dory

Comment: do you have VC class SWRevealControlller in storyboard ? join room !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check is if your  SWRevealViewController is not nil on `viewDidLoad()`

```
 if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        mainHomeButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        mainHomeButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

**Update**

Your storyboard structure need to be revised.
You should present your `SWRevealViewController`on login button click, not View Controller.

In storyboard segue should be link something like this:

1. login button -> SWRevealViewController
2. SWRevealViewController (sw_front) -> navigation controlller of home vc
3. SWRevealViewController (sw_rear) -> menu controller

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: what should i do ahead?

Comment: I have kind of similar structure, your storyboard structure does not seem proper. your front VC  should be your menu.

Comment: so what should i do now

Answer (score 1):

- `self.storyboard` could be `nil`.
- The identifier might not reference any view controller.
- The identifier could reference a view controller that isn't of type `ViewController`.
- The `mainHomeButton` outlet might not be hooked up.

Comment: everything is set ok

Comment: At least one of those things is incorrect.  Verify each one individually.  Log `self.storyboard`.  Log the result of `instantiateViewController` without force casting it.  Log `mainHomeButton`.

Comment: how should i do `Log mainHomeButton`

Comment: sir i have updated the question with architacture look at please!

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this instead:

```
@IBAction func loginAction(_sender: Any){
    let vc = ViewController()
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This is wrong because the view controller elements will not be initialized and will most likely crash as soon as he hits viewDidLoad(). He needs to use the method as above with instantiateViewController.

Comment: I don't use Storyboards, so I'm not sure how it works. My bad